# CDROM with Internet Access Required

Tags: mount

I have mounted a CDROM `sudo mount /dev/sr0 /mnt/iso`. However, the only thing that appears is an .htm file, which leads me to an outdated website page.

I know that this CDROM has .pdf files on it, but I cannot access it for some reason and it does not automatically open like it does in Windows.

So how can I being troubleshooting?

Comment: Right-click and open with Disk Image...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please [edit] your question and provide the exact mount command you used and the contents of the htm file.  It might be a DVDROM not using the Joliet format.

Comment: I'm not sure how you find the contents of an htm file. When I used xdg-open *.htm , it took me to an outdated website. Regards.